# arp table contains addresses asigned to 00:00:00:00:00:00 mac address

Tags: arp, mac-address, arptables

What mean `00:00:00:00:00:00` MAC address in arp table? On my OpenWRT router on interface connected to ISP I have seen 24 entries with this MAC address and on local network there are 7 entries. What these entries means or indicate?

Comment: a gui bug? reboot the router

Comment: I think your question is similar to this one which has valid answer: https://superuser.com/questions/821802/what-could-these-ip-addresses-with-mac-000000000000-be